# How to detect if the user device big or small in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, size, screen, device, platform

Basically I want to write a function that detect the size of device if its big or small

For example: 
Samsung S6, S7, S8 will not allow to use function because their size not big such as iPad or Samsung Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Platform.is()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#is) for this.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public platform: Platform)

public myFunction(){
  if(this.platform.is('tablet'){
    //execute function
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.